# CSV import row by row using ajax php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have searched over google and nothing found suitable to this.I would like to import csv in row by row using infinite ajax.

upload csv and show the progress of counted row processed and remaining row.

Also validate csv data before start importing in to mysql.

So in short the process would be in batch process one by one row read and insert it to MySQL.

Comment: Surely this is the same as submitting data from a form and saving it.  This needs to be wrapped in a Javascript loop to send the data line by line though.

Comment: You can try jquery plugin : https://cmatskas.com/importing-csv-files-using-jquery-and-html5/

Comment: it's create browser compatibility issue.also it doesn't provide ajax based process